# How to solved "Undefined offset: 4" in laravel inport CSV file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[image]Im try to import csv file in to DB
im using this library [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.com/)
But im have error
When im try use dd function im see reading only one line in the csv file, this is a heading rows 
After this rows im see only null
It looks like this

```
array:4 [
  0 => "OS_RAH;N_MARK;ZAV_NOMER;DIAM;N_MISC;DATA_VST;DATA_POV;DATA_NAST_POV;KIL_MISIAC;POP_POK;OST_POK;TIP;KON_POK;DATA_KON_POK;DATA_N_PLOMB;N_PLOMB"
  1 => null
  2 => null
  3 => null
]
```

If someone knows how to solve this problem, I will be very grateful

this is my code from import file

```
use Importable;
public function model(array $row)
{
    HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');
    return new ImportPassportCounter([
        'OS_RAH' => $row[0],
        'N_MARK' => $row[1],
        'ZAV_NOMER' => $row[2],
        'DIAM' => $row[3],
        'N_MISC' => $row[4],
        'DATA_VST' => $row[5],
        'DATA_POV' => $row[6],
        'DATA_NAST_POV' => $row[7],
        'KIL_MISIAC' => $row[8],
        'POP_POK' => $row[9],
        'OST_POK' => $row[10],
        'TIP' => $row[11],
        'KON_POK' => $row[12],
        'DATA_KON_POK' => $row[13],
        'DATA_N_PLOMB' => $row[14],
        'N_PLOMB' => $row[15],
    ]);
}

public function chunkSize(): int
{
    return 1000;
}
```

this is my code im Model file

```
class ImportPassportCounter extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'import_passport_counters';
    protected $fillable = [
        'OS_RAH',
        'N_MARK',
        'ZAV_NOMER',
        'DIAM',
        'N_MISK',
        'DATA_VST',
        'DATA_POV',
        'DATA_NAST_POV',
        'KIL_MISIAC',
        'POP_POK',
        'OST_POK',
        'TIP',
        'KON_POK',
        'DATA_KON_POK',
        'DATA_N_PLOMB',
        'N_PLOMB',
    ];
}
```

this is my migration file

```
Schema::create('import_passport_counters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text('OS_RAH')->nullable();
        $table->text('N_MARK')->nullable();
        $table->text('ZAV_NOMER')->nullable();
        $table->text('DIAM')->nullable();
        $table->text('N_MISK')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_VST')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_POV')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_NAST_POV')->nullable();
        $table->text('KIL_MISIAC')->nullable();
        $table->text('POP_POK')->nullable();
        $table->text('OST_POK')->nullable();
        $table->text('TIP')->nullable();
        $table->text('KON_POK')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_KON_POK')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_N_PLOMB')->nullable();
        $table->text('N_PLOMB')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

this is my code in Controller

```
$import = Excel::import(new PassportCounterImport, $request->file('file'));
    if ($import)
    {
        $result['success'] = true;
        $result['message'] = 'Success';
        return response()->json($result, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the CSV file please?

Comment: yes w8 a few seconds

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a semicolon seperated .csv file. In your `PassportCounterImport.php` add that you want to use custom settings and define the `delimeter`.

```
class PassportCounterImport implements WithCustomCsvSettings {
    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimeter' => ';',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is the path you need to take, sure you implemented the interface? and or which version are you running?

Comment: laravel or library?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",

Comment: Yes im sure in my interface because there is no problem importing Excel file

Comment: "Yes im sure in my interface because there is no problem importing Excel file" the interface your class also should implement has to do with customs settings and not importing. Ofc is should implement both.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PassportCounterImport implements ToModel, WithCustomCsvSettings {
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');
        return new ImportPassportCounter([
            'OS_RAH' => $row[0],
            'N_MARK' => $row[1],
            'ZAV_NOMER' => $row[2],
            'DIAM' => $row[3],
            'N_MISC' => $row[4],
            'DATA_VST' => $row[5],
            'DATA_POV' => $row[6],
            'DATA_NAST_POV' => $row[7],
            'KIL_MISIAC' => $row[8],
            'POP_POK' => $row[9],
            'OST_POK' => $row[10],
            'TIP' => $row[11],
            'KON_POK' => $row[12],
            'DATA_KON_POK' => $row[13],
            'DATA_N_PLOMB' => $row[14],
            'N_PLOMB' => $row[15],
        ]);
    }
    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ';',
        ];
    }
}
```

IS delimiter AND NOT delimeter




implements ToModel, WithCustomCsvSettings

AND PLUS

implements ToModel, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithStartRow

```
public function startRow(): int
{
    return 2;
}
```